# Delete shared preferences using an adb command

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to delete a shared preferences file using an adb command. Is there a way to do that without uninstalling the app?

I could not find anything that did it?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to clear all the preferences, a single command will do it:

`adb shell pm clear <package name>`

Comment: Thanks, Flavio! This worked for me. I found more info on this at: http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-pm-clear

Comment: FYI this deletes all app data, not just shared prefs

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not on an unrooted phone.  On normal consumer builds (user builds), only the application itself can access the app's data.

If you have root, you can access the shell via

```
adb shell
```

Then navigate to the app's data directory (`/data/data/<package name>`), find the file and `rm` it.

Alternatively, you can do it all at once with

```
adb shell rm /data/data/<package name>/<file name>
```

Comment: This worked for me, with root you can run `adb shell` then `su` then `rm -rf /data/data/<package name>/shared_prefs` to delete em all

Comment: This is not true. I'm able to delete any application's data using `adb shell pm clear <package>` on my unrooted Pixel 5.

Comment: @RicardoYubal that's sort of true. I was answering the question of whether you can delete a _specific_ file within the application's data directory. Your approach deletes the file, and everything else (which could be desired). Similar to uninstalling, and reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this on a DEBUG application only:

```
$ adb shell
$ adb run-as mypackagename

$ cd /data/data/mypackagename/shared_prefs
```

//then remove whatever you want